# What does $\operatorname{Tr}>0$ imply about complex eigenvalues of a Jacobi matrix?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, jacobian, stability-theory

I am currently taking a mathematical biology course and am working through the notes. We are covering stability analysis using the Jacobian matrix. One of the conditions for checking the stability is as follows: $$\text{Tr}(J)^2<4\det(J)\implies \lambda=\mu+i\omega.$$ It is also written that $\operatorname{Tr}(J)<0\implies \text{Stable Spiral}$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(J)>0\implies \text{Unstable Spiral}$.

Why does the trace have this effect on the stability of the spiral? I understand that $\operatorname{Tr}(J)^2<4\det(J)$ gives complex eigenvalues from a negative determinant when solving for them. If the real part $\mu<0$ does this generally imply stability? Is the only effect of the complex eigenvalues creating the spiral?

Comment: Are you familiar with Grobman-Hartman theorem?

Comment: It is only briefly mentioned as an appendix to the lecture notes. To my understanding it means that close to the steady state, behavior of a linear approximation matches the behavior of the original system.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So if the real parts of the eigenvalues are negative, then the solutions to the linear model tend to 0 and therefore the solutions of original model tend to the steady state (at least in some small neighbourhood). In your case the real part of both eigenvalues is $Tr(J)/2$, hence the stability results depending on the trace.